# LED Control with current sinking

Tags: current

I've been looking into the schematics for some Arduinos in detail to increase my understand of them. Take in particular the [Arduino Zero schematic](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/Zero_V1.0.pdf), we can see the RX/TX LEDs are connected as:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQSnEQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As per my understanding, the MCU pin can sink 10mA of current. How is the value of R1 (330\$\Omega\$ in this case) chosen? Assuming we have an LED with a forward voltage of 2V and current of 20mA. (I don't actually know what type of LED is on the Arduino Zero - any ideas?)

Comment: I wouldn't look to arduinos as stellar examples of design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did an image search, and <s>the LEDs on the Arduino Zero look green to me, so</s> I'm going to assume a forward voltage of 1.8 V.

If the supply voltage is 3.3 V and the LED forward voltage is 1.8 V, the resistor must drop 1.5 V.

Since I = U / R, then I = 1.5 V / 330 Ω = 4.55 mA.

My guess is that the value of 330 Ω is chosen because it gives a current that is well within spec, while probably also giving out enough light to be useful. But for a definitive answer you'll have to ask the designers.

Comment: The linked schematic says yellow leds are used.

Comment: In my defense, the picture was pretty bad (it's like deja vu with that black and blue dress, all over again). I should have thought of clicking the link though.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are correct and the LED is 2V, nominally that resistor will set the LED current at close to 4mA, which is enough to make it light up dimly without wasting too much power or straining the IO pin.

I can not of course speak for the original designer, but it seems a reasonable compromise. But then again, the original designer may just have thrown in a typical value, found it lit up well enough, and kept it as is.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably misunderstanding what the 20mA current rating of an LED means. This doesn't mean such a device *will* take 20mA; it will pass whatever comes from the V=IR equation which is determined by the supply voltage, forward voltage drop of the LED used and the current limiting LED (in a circuit like this).

Let's assume you're right and the LED has a forward voltage of 2V (which *is* an absolute rating -within its tolerances). This means you have 3.3-2 across the resistor.

So, the maths is:

1.3 = 330 * I

I = 1.3/330 which is 3.94mA.

If you dropped that LED to 33ohm, 39.4mA would pass through the LED which may well release the magic smoke as it would be outside of the processor's maximum operating range (and possibly outside of the LED's too).

You also need to remember that different LEDs have different recommended operating currents, so you pick the resistor in a circuit like this, to deliver the recommended current.

I have seen many applications where a massively larger amount of current is dumped into the LED, but it is fed with a PWM so its average current is within its recommended operating conditions.

Comment: "If you dropped that LED to 33ohm, 39.4mA would pass through the LED" it would if the bottom end were tied to ground, but not here, the Arduino is only good for 10mA.

Comment: Well, yes, the magic smoke might be released -  as I said! The point remains that reducing the resistor increases the current and it's not the LED that determines the current flow.

Comment: Worth modifying your answer to make it clear that the I/O pin will current limit at some point, or should be expected to and designed round. Then it's a clear answer for the OP.